# Enum value not found for "Normal" Maui App.xaml

Tags: c#, maui

Finishing migration from Xamarin to Maui .net 8 and i am getting the following error with no line numbers so i can pinpoint where the issue is.

below is app.xaml that it say erro is stemming from

In the code only thing using the normal enum is buttons.  I have searched have not seen this topic.  I am not in anyway a great xaml coder i am assembly and c embedded mostly.  SO take it easy on me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application
    x:Class="TwosenseChatterbox.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:TwosenseChatterbox.Behaviors"
    xmlns:themes="clr-namespace:TwosenseChatterbox.Themes;assembly=TwosenseChatterbox" 
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TwosenseChatterbox.ViewModels">
    <Application.Resources>
        <!--  Colors  -->

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <themes:LightTheme />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="locator" />
            <converters:StringToBoolConverter x:Key="EnabledWhenFilledConverter" />
            <converters:StringToFloatConverter x:Key="OpaqueWhenFilledConverter" />

            <!--  Styles  -->

            <Style x:Key="stackLayoutStyle" TargetType="StackLayout">
                <Setter Property="Orientation">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <OnIdiom
                            x:TypeArguments="StackOrientation"
                            Phone="Vertical"
                            Tablet="Horizontal" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="BlackTitleBar_Wrapper" TargetType="StackLayout">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,1" />
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="BlackTitleBar" TargetType="StackLayout">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#181818" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,5,10,5" />
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="WhiteTitleBarLabel" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
                <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold" />
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="EntryStyle" TargetType="Entry">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="PageTitleLg" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="FontSize">40</Setter>
                <Setter Property="FontAttributes">Bold</Setter>
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Secondary}" />
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="PageTitleMed" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="FontSize">25</Setter>
                <Setter Property="FontAttributes">Bold</Setter>
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Secondary}" />
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="PageTitleSm" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="FontSize">18</Setter>
                <Setter Property="FontAttributes">Bold</Setter>
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black" />
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="Hyperlink" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="FontSize">18</Setter>
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Secondary}" />
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="labelTitle" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="FontSize">17</Setter>
                <Setter Property="FontAttributes">Bold</Setter>
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black" />
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="label" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="FontSize">17</Setter>
                <Setter Property="FontAttributes">Normal</Setter>
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black" />
            </Style>


            <Style x:Key="StatusLabel" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="FontSize">17</Setter>
                <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold"/>
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource PrimaryDarkColor}" />
            </Style>




            <Color x:Key="CustomerColor">White</Color>
            <Color x:Key="QrColor">White</Color>
            <Color x:Key="SummColor">White</Color>
            <Color x:Key="AWSColor">White</Color>
            <Style x:Key="srTitle" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="CenterAndExpand" />
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black" />
                <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0, 0, 0, 6" />
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="srBody" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="48, 0" />
                <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalTextAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="CenterAndExpand" />
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="srLgTitle" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="22" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="CenterAndExpand" />
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource PrimaryDarkColor}" />
                <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0, 0, 0, 6" />
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="srLgBody" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="48, 0" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalTextAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="None"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="CenterAndExpand" />
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="BlackTitleBarLabel" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
                <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold" />
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="BlackTitleBarLabelLarge" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="45" />
                <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold" />
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="boldWhiteTextLabel" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13" />
                <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold" />
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="blackTextLabel" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#181818" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13" />
                <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="None" />
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="whiteTextLabel" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13" />
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="listViewWrapper" TargetType="StackLayout">
                <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical" />
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#181818" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,1,0,1" />
                <Setter Property="Spacing" Value="0" />

            </Style>


            <!--  List View Light  -->

            <Style x:Key="listViewLight" TargetType="StackLayout">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="20,10,20,10" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0" />
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="listViewLightBorder" TargetType="StackLayout">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,1" />
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#E8E8E8" />
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="listViewLightTitle" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Secondary}" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="26" />
                <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold" />
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="listViewLightTitleMed" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
                <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold" />
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="listViewLightTitleSm" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="17" />
                <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold" />
            </Style>



            <Style x:Key="ValueLabel" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="FontSize">12</Setter>
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black" />
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="listViewLightLabel" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#484848" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalTextAlignment" Value="Center" />
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="listViewDarkLabel" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Small" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalTextAlignment" Value="Center" />
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="listViewDarkTitle" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="LightGray" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Large" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalTextAlignment" Value="Center" />
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="DefaultFrame" TargetType="Frame">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="Transparent" />

                <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="FillAndExpand" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="FillAndExpand" />
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="ActionFrame" TargetType="Frame">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#002d72" />
                <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="#0072ce" />
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="20" />
                <Setter Property="HasShadow" Value="True" />
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="CognitoButton" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#002d72" />
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="15" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="30,0" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10" />
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial-Rounded" />
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="CognitoRegistrationButton" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Green" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="FillAndExpand" />
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24" />
                <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="76" />
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="CognitoEntry" TargetType="Entry">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="FillAndExpand" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,12" />
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="CognitoPasswordEntry" TargetType="Entry">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="FillAndExpand" />
                <Setter Property="IsPassword" Value="True" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,12" />
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="CognitoLabel" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="FillAndExpand" />
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Medium" />
            </Style>


            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                    <VisualStateGroupList>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Secondary}" />
                                    <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                                    <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateGroupList>
                </Setter>
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="LightGrayBtn" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black" />
                <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                    <VisualStateGroupList>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Gray-200}" />
                                    <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Gray-100}" />
                                    <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateGroupList>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: You wrote "_i am getting the following error..._" but you never actually posted the full error message, details, and where you saw it (Build error list? XAML Binding Errors list? Runtime exception?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I inferred that your error is here:

```
            <Style x:Key="label" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="FontSize">17</Setter>
                <Setter Property="FontAttributes">Normal</Setter>
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black" />
            </Style>
```

[The `enum Microsoft.Maui.Controls.FontAttributes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.fontattributes?view=net-maui-8.0) type does not have a member named `Normal` - change it to `None`.

...curiously, [`Xamarin.Forms.FontAttributes` *also* lacks a `Normal` member too](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.fontattributes?view=xamarin-forms), so I wonder where you got `Normal` from in the first place.

Comment: Yes that fixed it thanks i did check it is in my Xamarin code same way as well